# Docker Toolbox の localhost にアクセスできない

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox

Windows 10 で Docker Toolbox でホストの localhost 8080 番ポートをコンテナのポートに繋いだ後 `http://localhost:8080` にアクセスしても接続を拒否されます。

なぜでしょうか？

以下が Docker Toolbox のターミナル上での実行ログです。

```
$ docker run -d -p 8080:80 --rm httpd:2.4.41
$ curl http://localhost:8080
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker Toolbox はバックエンドとして VirtualBox を使っている関係で、デフォルトでは localhost（`127.0.0.1`）からアクセスできず、別の IP アドレスからアクセスできるようになっています。このアドレスは `docker-machine ip default` で確認できます。私の環境では `192.168.99.100` でした。

```
$ docker-machine ip default
192.168.99.100
$ curl http://192.168.99.100:8080
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
```

英語版 Stack Overflow での類似質問: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42866013/5989200